Combining API call with messaging queue
We are building an application that will be responsible for updating a backend system.
The application can be considered as a  CRUD application with a business logic component in the middle.
Client -> API -> Business logic -> Database

To decouple the backend system (in this case the database) I am considering to use a queue in between.
Client -> API --> Queue -> Worker -> Database
           ^                |
           |----< Queue <---|

Not only this queue will decouple the backend but it will also provide throttling and garantuees order, which is extremely important.
Is this a good idea ? Has anyone already implemented something like this ?
Thank you,
